# IotHub device endpoint not showing messages

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub

I have created a python script that scraps data from a API and pushes it into Azure Iothub.

Currently the script sends messages to IotHub, and i get no errors sending them. But when i try to view the messages coming in via Visual studio nothing appears. I am also trying to route the messages into a stream analytics job but nothing comes through.

Now the confusing thing is i have created a new IotHub and just out the connection strings in my script. And the messages are viewable in Visual studio.

Im really clueless as to what i could try to get my messages visible in my main IotHub, so any suggestions would be super helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can just configure message routing and save it to the blob storage as a JSON structure, or you run this command with required parameters in Azure CLI

```
az iot device simulate -n {iothub_name} -d {device_id}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, this was really interesting to do. When i simulated against my newly created IoTHub and device it worked and i saw the messages coming through in visual studio. But when i simulated against my original IoTHub the messages don't come through the device. Im guessing its something to do with the IotHub settings, will have to keep digging. Thanks for the tip tho

Comment: I think then surely there is some settings misconfiguration just verified that if there is any message routing configured already then the message might do not come here.